# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 4

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

i have written my own algorithms to determine the edges and then find the corner points.
But then am having trouble in prespective transforming the image.I have written some code to achieve the result but am getting the above specified error.
Could anyone help please me out.
Thanks in advance!

```
    Mat mat = new Mat(w, h, CvType.CV_32S);

    MatOfPoint2f finalc = new MatOfPoint2f();

    MatOfPoint2f ma = new MatOfPoint2f();

    mat.put(0, 0, array);

    Mat quad = new Mat(w,h,CvType.CV_32S);

    quad.put(0,0,w,0,w,h,0,w);

ma.put((int)a[0][1],(int)a[0][0],(int)a[1][1],(int)a[1][0],(int)a[2][1],(int)a[2][0],(int)a[3][1],(int)a[3][0]);

    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(ma,finalc,2.0,true);

    Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(finalc, quad);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(mat, quad, transmtx, quad.size());

    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", quad, matOfByte); 

    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();

    //InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

    //BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);

    File f = new File("retrieve1.jpg");

    BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(w, h, 12);

    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster)img1.getData();

    raster.setDataElements(0,0,w,h,byteArray);

    img1.setData(raster);

    try
    {

        ImageIO.write(img1,"jpg",f);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

all i am basically trying to do is port a part of this (C++) code to java.
https://github.com/bsdnoobz/opencv-code/blob/master/quad-segmentation.cpp

Comment: Please format your code. And only post relevant parts.

Comment: 4 is CvType.CV_32S, so maybe your data is not using this type.

Comment: @andy thanks for your response. But when i use CV_8UC1 i get the following error:OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32S || depth == CV_
32F)) in cv::approxPolyDP, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.
cpp, line 1871

Comment: have you try CV_ 32F?

Comment: @andy ya tried it now but it shows mat data type is not compatible:5

Comment: @andy and also my "array" in the above code is a byte array. Is that a possible factor too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution i created:

```
    Mat mat = new Mat(h,w, CvType.CV_8U);

    mat.put(0, 0, array);

    //Imshow is = new Imshow("try");for verification

    MatOfPoint2f quad = new MatOfPoint2f(p);//array of corner points

    MatOfPoint2f rect = new MatOfPoint2f(farray);//final array of corner points into which mat should be warped into

    Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(quad,rect);

    Mat output = new Mat(w,h,CvType.CV_8U); 

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(mat, output, transmtx, new Size(w,h),Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);

    //is.showImage(output);     

    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", output, matOfByte); 

    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();

    File f = new File("retrieve1.jpg");

    BufferedImage img1 =null;

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

    img1  = ImageIO.read(in);

    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster)img1.getData();

    raster.setDataElements(0,0,byteArray);

    img1.setData(raster);
```

Since i didn't need to verify corner points hence i removed approxpolydp and put everything in as points instead of directly feeding them into the matofpoint2fs. And "array" is the byte equivalent of the image in use.